# How to unlist a list to a specific level

Tags: r, excel

The following function can be used to load an entire excel workbook

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library("xlsx")
library(readxl)   
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) 
{
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
names(x) <- sheets
x
}
mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets(choose.files())
```

I am trying to find a way to unlist all worksheets into the global environment as separate dataframes. Thusfar I have been accesing them one at a time using mysheets$, but this inefficient for the large workbooks am using.

I have tried

```
unlist(mysheets, recursive=F)
```

but it does not provide the desired result.

Comment: The `lapply` output is a `list`.  So, you have a `list` of datasets.  If you need to have a single file `mysheets %>% bind_rows` or in `base R` `do.call(rbind, mysheets)` (assuming the column names are the same)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what is inefficient about using `mysheets$`. You could rename `mysheets` to a shorter name if that's what's bothering you. If you *really* want to move the dfs to the global environment, you could use this hack:

```
for (s in names(mysheets)) {
  eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s <- mysheets[['%s']]", make.names(s), s)))
}
rm(mysheets)
```

Note that the dfs' names will be changed by make.names. If you'd like to keep the names change the line in the for statement to:

```
eval(parse(text = sprintf("`%s` <- mysheets[['%s']]", s, s)))
```